# Multiple CRA in a single Wordpress plugin?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, plugins, create-react-app

I'm creating a Wordpress plugin using react (with `create-react-app`). I need my react app in different places like Dashboard, User Profile, Custom Admin page, Frontend Page etc. So if I build a single bundle for all of them, it'll add unnecessary size to the JS file and can increase the load time. But if I create different `CRA` for all of them, I won't be able to share components between them.

Edit:

The structure look like this:

- Components used by ALL

  1. CommonComponent1
  2. CommonComponent2.....
- Components used ONLY by `Dashboard` JS

  1. DashboardComponent1
  2. DashboardComponent2.....
- Components used ONLY by `User Profile` JS

  1. UPComponent1
  2. UPComponent2.....

and so on..

So to optimize file sizes, I will need to load only the Dashboard components and the Common components for `Dashboard`. And for `User Profile` only the UPComponents and the Common Components. And so on...

How can I solve this problem?

Please ask if additional information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single `package.json` and link packages using [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html)

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "link:../node_modules/react",
    "react-dom": "link:../node_modules/react-dom",
    "react-scripts": "link:../node_modules/react-scripts",
  },
```

Comment: Sorry but i think there might be a slight misunderstanding. Please read the updated question again. Thank you.